# Get specific object from JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have this:

```
'{
"Games": [
    {   "champion": 126,
        "season": 9
    },
    {
        "champion": 126,
        "season": 9
    }, {
        "champion": 126,
        "season": 8
    }`
```

And i want only to take champion number that's only from season 9. How can i do that?

Comment: Kindly post complete valid json data.

Comment: For loop. Have you tried anything?

Comment: What do you expect the output to be? `[126, 126]`?

Comment: [Array find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.find`:

```
const champion = data.Games.find(({season}) => season === 9)
```

or ES5

```
var champion = data.Games.find(function(champion) {
   return champion.season === 9;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you must iterate over the array with conditional logic to capture and return any values that you are looking for.

Something like:

```
for (var i = 0; i < Games.length; i++) {
    if (Games[i].season == 9) {
        return(Games[i].champion);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Array.filter()

```
var season9 = Games.filter(function(elem) {
    return (elem.season === 9);
});
```

or in Es6

```
let season9 = Games.filter(elem => elem.season === 9);
```

then

```
var champions = season9.map(function(elem) {
   return elem.champion;
})
```

or in Es6

```
let champions = season9.map(elem => elem.champion);

console.log(champions) // => [126, 126]
```

Comment: let result = Games.filter(elem => elem.season === 9).map(elem => elem.champion);